# Gremlin-Groovy Syntax

Tags: groovy, amazon-dynamodb, titan, gremlin

I am using Gremlin-Groovy to query an AWS hosted graph database (Titan on DynamoDB). I can query the outgoing follow relationship of a person with the following query:

```
"gremlin": "g.V().has(p0,p1).out(p2)",
"bindings": {
    "p0": "PersonId",
    "p1": "b72a0ff5-21ca-4c71-9c47-20bef36ac277",
    "p2": "follow"
 }
```

I also want to be able to count the number of followings of each of the followings this query generates. Is it possible to do it in one query ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you might do it:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV(id,'a').as('a').
......1>   addV(id,'b').as('b').
......2>   addV(id,'c').as('c').
......3>   addV(id,'d').as('d').
......4>   addV(id,'e').as('e').
......5>   addV(id,'f').as('f').
......6>   addV(id,'g').as('g').
......7>   addE('follows').from('a').to('b').
......8>   addE('follows').from('b').to('c').
......9>   addE('follows').from('b').to('d').
.....10>   addE('follows').from('a').to('e').
.....11>   addE('follows').from('a').to('f').
.....12>   addE('follows').from('f').to('g').iterate()
gremlin> g.V().has(id,'a').out('follows').
......1>   group().by().by(out('follows').count())
==>[v[b]:2,v[e]:0,v[f]:1]
```

You can see that the last line returns a `Map` where the person vertices that "a" follows are the keys and the values represent the count of those people that they each follow.